# Delete all files including files with spaces BATCH

Tags: batch-file

I'm looking for a way to delete all files in a directory that are older than `x` days and that are not of certain extension, I found this command line for the first:

```
forfiles -p "C:\Test" -s -m *.* /D -5 /C "cmd /c del @path"
```

and this for the second:

```
for /f %%F in ('dir /b /a-d ^| findstr /vile ".bat"') do del "%%F"
```

but could not do them in one command line, and for the second it ignores files containing spaces in their names.

Note that I am doing this in batch files (`DeleteOldFiles.bat`).
Thanks to everyone in advance.

Comment: batch file or from cmdline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FORFILES` command does have an option to see what the file extension is.  So all you have to do is use that variable to compare it with the extension you are trying to exclude.

```
forfiles -p "C:\Test" -s -m *.* /D -5 /C "cmd /c if /I not @ext==0x22bat0x22 del @path"
```

The 0x22 is the hex representation of the double quote.  Forfiles variables are always quoted.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted, I just added relative directory to delete files in the directory of the batch file without deleting the batch file itself, so thanks very much. 'forfiles -p %~dp0 -s -m *.* /D -60 /C "cmd /c if /I not @ext==0x22bat0x22 del @path"'

Answer (score 0):

When using a for loop with `/f` certain special characters are default delimeters. One of those being a space, so a name with a space will be split by space. So we need to ad `"delims="` to override default delims.

I however suspect that you want to run both deletion of old files and excluding certain bat extensions purely because you batch file might be in the sam directory as the files you want to delete. You can overcome this simply by placing the file elsewhere and specifying path to the directory where files needs deleting. If so then simply add this to the batch file and place the file in a seperate dir:

```
    forfiles -p "C:\Test" -s -m *.* /D -5 /C "cmd /c del @path"
```

If you want to delete all other files from a dir which containsa batch files and seperately delete files older than N date in another then these will do.

Batch file version:

```
@echo off
forfiles -p "C:\Test" -s -m *.* /D -5 /C "cmd /c del @path"
for /f  "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d ^| findstr /vile ".bat"') do echo del "%%F"
pause
```

Cmdline version:

```
forfiles -p "C:\Test" -s -m *.* /D -5 /C "cmd /c del @path" & for /f  "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d ^| findstr /vile ".bat"') do echo del "%%F"
```

Be careful though where you place the batch file as there is no specific path in the command for the `for` loop. For that very reason, I placed `echo` before `del` once you are sure that your query `echo`'s the result you expect, you can remove the `echo` to perform the actual task.

Comment: The directory I'm working on is a directory for temporary most word and excel files created on the basis of model files in the upper directory, I keep these files after printing them until I'am sure there was no error, and that they was signed by the director and sent to destination. As you suspected, I wanted to put the batch file in the same directory as the files for some reasons and I prefer to do so for that the answer of @Squashman was exactly what I want, although your answer was helpful to me. So thanks for you two.